# Loop Array to Modify Values (JavaScript to PHP and Back to JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, foreach

I'm working with JavaScript and PHP using arrays, the first step is create the array, here

```
var ListaA=[];
var i = 0, len = options.length;
while (i < len){
            var tmp = {
                        'proyecto':'test',
                        'pendientes1':0,
                        'pendientes2':0,
                        'terminadas1':0,
                        'terminadas2':0,
                        'solucion':0
                };
                ListaA.push(tmp);
                i++;
            }
```

Then i send it to my PHP file like this

```
var laLista = JSON.stringify(ListaA);

$.get("php/operation.php?test="+ {'test' : laLista }, function( data ){
                var tmp = {
                        'proyecto':""+value['proyecto']+"",
                        'pendientes1':""+value['pendientes1']+"",
                        'pendientes2':""+value['pendientes2']+"",
                        'terminadas1':""+value['terminadas1']+"",
                        'terminadas2':""+value['terminadas2']+"",
                        'solucion':""+value['solucion']+""
                    };
                    ListaA.push(tmp);
            });
```

As you can see above i have ready the code to get the data which represents the array sent by the PHP file, so i got covered that part, my issue here is in my PHP file, here.

```
$arrayWork = json_decode($_POST['test']);
```

Then i want to loop, this time, just for testing i'm just taking one of the values and incresing it to watch the result, like this

```
foreach($arrayWork as $value){
     $value['pendientes1']++; // this is not working for me
}
```

I got the following: "invalid argument supplied in foreach". So, what's wrong with my code? and which is the properly way to loop it and return it to my JavaScript?

I hope you can help me out with this issue. Thank you for your time and attention, good night.

Comment: In php code `$arrayWork or $_POST['test']` it should be empty because in javascript you are using get request and in php you try to get data from a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this code

```
$arrayWork = json_decode($_POST['test']);
```

your json isn't really converted into an associated array, look at below

> mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
>
> assoc
>   When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

To convert json object into an array just add `true` to the second parameter to it

```
$arrayWork = json_decode($_POST['test'], true);**strong text**
```

To increment an index value in an array

```
foreach($arrayWork $key => as $value){
    $arrayWork['pendientes1']++;
}
```

Edited.

also since you are using `$_POST` method change your ajax from `$.get` to `$.post`

```
$.post("php/operation.php?test="+ {'test' : laLista }, function( data ){
      var result = JSON.parse(data); // parse json string into json object
       ...
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i get it, but how about my loop sentence in my PHP file? or also i have to modify it to make it work properly?

Comment: Awesome, but you don't get me, i mean, the way that i'm looping in PHP     foreach($arrayWork as $value){...} is it correct? or also i have to modify it?

Comment: your goal in that line is to increment `$value['pendientes1']++` alone

Comment: Yeah, only that just for test if the foreach sentece is working correctly.

Comment: @Gutierrez check my updated answer, I added the increment

Comment: I got  it perfectly, i appreciate yours answers, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read `$_POST`, you have to make a POST request:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'php/operation.php',
  type:"POST",
  data: { test: ListaA },
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(){
    ...
  }
})
```

You can't use `$.post`, because you have to set the `contentType` to JSON.

**Important**: you don't need to run `JSON.stringify`yourself, jQuery will take care of it for you - so pass the original `ListaA` array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and how about my foreach sentence? is it correct? or also i have to modify it?  foreach($arrayWork as $value){...}